# SwiftUI Button not responding when added Padding to it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

```
    struct ContactView: View {
    
    @Binding var isContactViewActive: Bool
    @State var searchBar = ""
    
    var backgroundColor = Color(red: 14/255, green: 18/255, blue: 23/255, opacity: 1.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                backgroundColor
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").font(.title)
                        })
                        Spacer()
                        Text("FireChat")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "power").font(.title)
                        })
                    }.padding(.top, 50)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to add padding(.top, 50) around my HStack to position it a bit lower, my buttons stop responding on the image area and are only clickable on the padded area above. I do not understand why this is the case and how can i place my HStack lower without disturbing the buttons' clicking area.

Comment: The code you shared seems to be working fine on my side.Don’t know if I got your question correctly

Comment: works well for me too. There must be something else in your code that you are not showing us.

Comment: okay it doesn't work if i wrap this HStack with a VStack and also add a Spacer()

like this:
VStack {
  HStack { ... the above code }
  Spacer()
}

Comment: works well for me with the VStack and the Spacer.

Comment: anywhere i can share a video of the problem that I am facing?

Comment: I've put up the code I'm using, show us the code that you are using.

Comment: i am unable to paste the complete code here in the comment section. character limitation

Comment: you can edit your question and paste the code there.

Comment: i have edited the question you may check the code that I am using

Comment: tried your code works well for me. I updated my test code as well.

Comment: I am sorry but there's also a Spacer() after HStack

Comment: ok, I think that because you have "ZStack {...}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)" 
introducing the Spacer after the HStack put the ZStack under the NavigationView.
Removing ".edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)" makes it work, 
but that's probably not how you want to display the view.

Comment: yes, i want to cover the entire display to change the background color

Comment: you could remove "NavigationView {...}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)", since you are not using it.

Comment: this worked, removed NavigationView which i will be needing later but I will do something about it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be clear this is the code I'm using for testing:

```
    @main
    struct TestApp: App {
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
    
struct ContactView: View {
    
    @Binding var isContactViewActive: Bool
    @State var searchBar = ""
    
    var backgroundColor = Color(red: 14/255, green: 18/255, blue: 23/255, opacity: 1.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                backgroundColor
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {print("magnifyingglass")}, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").font(.title)
                        })
                        Spacer()
                        Text("FireChat")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {print("power")}, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "power").font(.title)
                        })
                    }.padding(.top, 50)
                }
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isContactViewActive = false
    var body: some View {
        ContactView(isContactViewActive: $isContactViewActive)
    }
}
```